# Assign properties inside or outside of TransactionScope?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008, linq-to-sql, transactionscope

I am using SQL Server 2008 and Linq-to-SQL.

`a` is object materialized from database using Linq-to-SQL. All its properties has `Auto-Sync` set to `Always`. `GetXxxxx()` is HTTP request to Webservice. It does not contain any nested transactions. Usually it takes not more than few seconds, but sometimes it can take up to 3-4-5-10 minutes.

So... Which one is preferred?

```
using (var t = new TransactionScope())
{
    a.Xxxxx = GetXxxxx();
    a.UpdatedOn = DateTime.UtcNow;
    database.SubmitChanges();
    a.Signature = CalculateSignature(a);
    database.SubmitChanges();
    t.Complete();
}
```

Or:

```
a.Xxxxx = GetXxxxx();
a.UpdatedOn = DateTime.UtcNow;
using (var t = new TransactionScope())
{
    database.SubmitChanges();
    a.Signature = CalculateSignature(a);
    database.SubmitChanges();
    t.Complete();
}
```

1st variant looks clearer. But what if `GetXxxxx()` will take 3-4-5-10 minutes? `TransactionScope` will block whole website in this case? So correct one is 2nd?

Comment: what is `a` and what is it's scope..? also please explain more what the heck you are talking about in regards to the `a.Xxxxx = GerXxxxx()`

Comment: Conversely, if you initialize your variables outside the scope and GetXxxxx is a blocking call, then your a.UpdatedOn timestamp will be older than the actual update.  You might set that after the blocking call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `System.Transactions.Transaction` starts on the first database call made while it is active. This means that both variants do the same this assuming that the two lines you moved do not call the database.

That makes this a matter of style. Pick what makes your intent the clearest.

Serializable isolation does not block the whole database. I consider this out of scope for the question but you can easily find information about this on the web.

Comment: The first answer on case. I was using 1st variant and it worked okay. But now due to DDoS on third-party server `GetXxxxx()` became unstable. And I see there is difference between 1st and 2nd variants. 2nd variant is okay: it causes `WebException` or `ThreadAbortException` in `GetXxxxx()` as expected. But 1st looks like it blocks other db requests: website hangouts and random db exceptions: `TransactionException The operation is not valid for the state of the transaction.` and `SqlException Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to ...`. Do not quite understand what is going on?

Comment: Maybe GetXxxxx uses the database? I can't sport the error with the code given. Post more and post all exception with all details.

Answer (score 1):

Denise Skidmore says about problems with UpdatedOn field that you can faces when use 2ed approach.

But if you worry about blocking whole DB you can change [IsolationLevel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.transactions.isolationlevel(v=vs.110).aspx) of `TransactionScope`. Default isolation level is `Serializable`

> Volatile data can be read but not modified, and no new data can be
>   added during the transaction.

So to avoid blocking you can change it to `ReadCommitted`

> Volatile data cannot be read during the transaction, but can be
>   modified.

Or even `ReadUncommitted`

> Volatile data can be read and modified during the transaction.

You can do it like this:

```
var transactionOptions = new TransactionOptions();
transactionOptions.IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted;
using (var t = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, transactionOptions))
{
    a.Xxxxx = GetXxxxx();
    a.UpdatedOn = DateTime.UtcNow;
    database.SubmitChanges();
    a.Signature = CalculateSignature(a);
    database.SubmitChanges();
    t.Complete();
}
```